# How can i detect which item from the dropdown list is deselected

Tags: angular

I have a dropdown list. Where on selection I am creating new form controls where the user should full the forms, which language he knows, the proficiency level and time of experience. He can press multiple choices but sometimes he can make a mistake and deselect something. Also here I have and validation error. It is working when he selects for example two forms it works only on the second but not on the first one. Any ideas?

```html
<h1>Set up you profile</h1>

<h1>Select the languages that you have knowledge of</h1>

<select class="selectingPL" #selectModel="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="selectedLevel" (change)="selected(i)" multiple>
    <option *ngFor="let item of allProgrammingLanguages;let i = index" [ngValue]="item">
        {{item}}
    </option>
</select>
```

```js
  selectedLevel: any = 'C#';
  // skills:FormGroup;

  userForm: any;

  arr = [];
  alreadyInside = [];

  isItConfirmed = false;

  isItValid = false;

  selected(event) {
    this.arr = this.selectedLevel;


    (<FormArray>this.userForm.get('skills')).push(this.addSkillFormGroup());
    this.isItConfirmed = true;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.arr.length; i++)
    {
      // console.log(this.userForm.get('skills'))
      this.userForm.get('skills').valueChanges.subscribe(x => {
        // console.log("*")
        // console.log(this.arr.length)
        console.log(this.userForm.get('skills').controls)
        for (let i = 0; i < this.arr.length; i++) {

    //
   if(this.userForm.get('skills').controls[i].controls.experienceInYears.invalid)
          if (x[i].experienceInYears == "" || x[i].proficiency == "") {
            this.canProceed = false;
          }


          else if (x[i].experienceInYears !== "" || x[i].proficiency !== "") {
            this.canProceed = true;
          }
        }
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you create demo code on stackblitz.com, please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a second variable for this

```
private oldSelection: any;
```

and in your method `selected` just do this:

```
selected(event) {
    if(!this.oldLevel && !this.arr){  //firstTime scenario
       this.oldLevel = this.selectedLevel;
    }else{
       this.oldLevel = this.arr;
    }
    this.arr = this.selectedLevel;
    //Your implementation
}
```

Here for first time both old and new value will be same and for next times, the previous value will be assigned to `oldLevel` and other will be updated with current selection.